# ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found -- IBM DB2

Tags: python-3.x, db2, pyinstaller

I know there have been many people with this same issue, but here is my situation which I have not been able to find the exact same problem.  I am building an executable with pyinstaller and I keep getting the importError.  I am using ibm_db package to connect to a IBM DB2 database and do inserts into a table using pandas to_sql method.  I used pyinstaller on my program before I added the SQL code so I'm pretty sure it has something to do with my trying to connect to DB2, but for the life of me I cannot figure this out.

I get lots of warnings and info messages when I"m running pyinstaller but no errors that I see.  I only get the error once I try to execute the executable file that pyinstaller built.

I have tried to run it in a virtual environment to try to isolate the issue but I am not that familiar with virtual environments, so I stop trying to use that.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "rebate_gui_sql.py", line 9, in <module>
  File "c:\users\dt24358\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py", line 627, in exec_module
    exec(bytecode, module.__dict__)
  File "site-packages\ibm_db.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "site-packages\ibm_db.py", line 9, in __bootstrap__
  File "imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
[11020] Failed to execute script rebate_gui_sql
```

Update: 5/1/2019 from comment below, here is my simple program

```
import pandas as pd
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk
import ibm_db
import ibm_db_dbi as db
from sqlalchemy import create_engine

class Application(Frame):

    def __init__(self, master):
        ttk.Frame.__init__(self, master)  
        self.master = master
        self.run_process()

    def run_process(self):
        engine = create_engine("db2+ibm_db://userid:password@url:port/database")
        conn = engine.connect()
        print("Connected to " + str(engine))

        sql = '''
            Select *
            from rebteam.pd5
            fetch first row only
            '''

        df = pd.read_sql(sql, conn)
        print(df)

        df.to_csv(r'c:\users\dt24358\scripts\pricing tool\GUI_SQL\test.csv', index=False)
        self.result_label = Label(root, text="Select of PD5 Successful", bg="light green", width=80, justify=LEFT)
        self.result_label.grid(row=0,columnspan=2)

root=Tk()
root.title("Rebate Bid Data Upload")
root.configure(background="light green")
app = Application(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: What platform and version of Db2?  AFAIK, the python package is designed for Db2 Linux,Unix,Windows (LUW).  If connecting to Db2 for i (AS/400 iSeries) or Z/OS you need to purchase and install the Db2 Connect product.

Comment: Do you have the Db2 client installed? If so, what package exactly? If not, you should.

Comment: @Charles -- we are running DB2 version 11.1 Fixpack 2 on AIX 7.1

Comment: @mustaccio -- I'm not sure what you mean by DB2 client?  I have the ibm_db package and ibm_db_dbi package installed and I'm using sqlalchemy.  As I said, I can get the program to work just fine if I run via shell, but when I compile it using pyinstaller, I run into the above error.

Comment: @mao -- I installed ibm_db and ibm_dbi using PIP install (not easy_install).  I'm running on Python 3.7.3, running 32-bit.

Comment: @mao -- I tried all your suggestions. I uninstalled ibm_db, ibm_db_sa, pyinstaller.  I even upgraded by version of pip to 19.1.  Set my db2 client using IBM_DB_HOME, then reinstalled ibm_db, ibm_db_sa, and pyinstaller.  Unfortunately, I'm still getting the same error message.  Does anyone else have any other possible options?  I am running on Windows 10 (32-bit version of Python 3.7.3).

Comment: well do, thanks for the suggestion Mao

Comment: @Mao -- I wrote a pretty simple program that is using the base components of my original program.  This program is just doing a select from the table that I'm trying to insert records into.  The code works fine when i run it through the shell, but once I use pyinstaller I am getting the same error as before.  Here is the code:

Comment: See my new code above under the "Update from 5/1"

Comment: @Kyle check revised answer, the worarounds allow your sample to run after pyinstaller.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This answer is relevant for these versions:

```
python - up to 3.7 (but not higher)  
pyinstaller 3.4  
setuptools 41.0.1 
ibm_db 3.0.1
ibm_db_sa 0.3.4
sqlalchemy 1.3.3
```

There are separate issues here.

The immediate issue (the ImportError) is the failure to load `ibm_db.dll`

The ImportError happens because pyinstaller does not copy external (non python) libraries into the bundle unless you explicitly request that to happen.

pyinstaller will also not copy a Db2-client into the bundle unless you explicitly tell it to do that, which means that if your target hostname to which you deploy your built-executable does not already have a preconfigured preinstalled Db2-client then you will also experience the failure to load ibm_db module.

The pyinstaller option `--add-binary` gives  a workaround for some kinds of ImportError , see example below. If you are not using SQLAlchemy just skip those parts of this answer.

The pyinstaller option `--add-data` gives a workaround for adding directories (for example the clidriver directory for adding a Db2-driver) when your target environment lacks a Db2-driver.

Note that this answer does not require you to use SQLAlchemy, the answer is also relevant if you are only using ibm_db (or ibm_db_dbi), in which case just skip the SQLAlchemy parts.

If your python script uses SQLAlchemy to access Db2, then you may see a second symptom at run time after building with pyinstaller. The run time symptom is either:

> "sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin:
> sqlalchemy.dialects:ibm_db_sa"

or

> "sqlalchemy.exc.NoSuchModuleError: Can't load plugin:
> sqlalchemy.dialects:db2.ibm_db"

(depending on the prefix for the url given to create_engine())

This symptom sqlalchemy.exe.NoSuchModuleError is not specific to Db2 but can impact other databases when used via SQLAlchemy with an ***external*** dialect ( Db2, teradata, snowflake, presto,...).  Databases that use SQLAlchemy internal dialects may just work out of the box.

Here is one workaround for SQLAlchemy, other workarounds are possible.

SQLAlchemy external dialects use pkg_resources entry_points to  allow SQLAlchemy to exploit them, but pyinstaller cannot yet handle these, without some assistance from you. Such entry point information is a kind of meta data about the module.

This workaround uses pyinstaller hooks to collect the metadata of the relevant modules , and tells pyinstaller the directory (or directories) that contain these hook files.  For Db2 with SQLAlchemy, three hook files are needed, `hook-ibm_db.py,  hook-ibm_db_sa.py,  hook-sqlalchemy.py`.  I choose to put these hook files in the same directory as my source file python script.

The contents of each of these files is trivial two lines, and the contents differ only by the module name contained within.  Here is an example of one of the files `hook-sqlalchemy.py` (for the other 2 required files, just replace the module name appropriately):

```
from PyInstaller.utils.hooks  import  copy_metadata

datas = copy_metadata('sqlalchemy')
```

To add `ibm_db.dll` via the `--add-binary method`, you can either use a command line option to pyinstaller or edit the spec file.

For handling load failures of ibm_db.dll alone, just use the --add-binary additional option like this:

```
pyinstaller -y --add-binary  %LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\ibm_db_dlls\ibm_db.dll;.\ibm_db_dlls your_script.py
```

If you want to include clidriver in your bundle, first find the fully qualified pathname to its location via:

`pip show ibm_db`

and in the output of that command see the `Location:` line which has the first part of the fully qualified pathname , so you append `\CLIDRIVER` to that path and use it in the `--add-data` additional option like this:

`--add-data="c:\path\to\clidriver;.\clidriver"`

If you do include clidriver in your bundle, there are additional considerations, see the notes section below.

For apps that also use SQLAlchemy, you need additional steps.

Suppose that the ibm_db.dll lives in this directory:

```
%LOCALAPPDATA%\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\ibm_db_dlls
```

and you make a variable in a CMD.EXE shell to point to that location:

```
> set ibm_db_path=%LOCALAPPDATA%\programs\python\python37\lib\site-packages\ibm_db_dlls
```

For an MS-Windows batch file (using ^ as line continuation character), the pyinstaller command line example to handle both of the workarounds mentioned above is:

```
pyinstaller -y ^
--additional-hooks-dir=. ^
--hidden-import ibm_db_sa.ibm_db ^
--hidden-import ibm_db_dbi ^
--hidden-import ibm_db ^
--add-binary  %LOCALAPPDATA%\Programs\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\ibm_db_dlls\ibm_db.dll;.\ibm_db_dlls ^
 your_script.py
```

**Notes:**

- If your python script explicitly imports the SQLAlchemy modules then you do not
  need to specify them via `--hidden-import` options (buy you still need
  the hooks for SQLAlchemy to operate after bundling).
- For ibm_db versions up to 3.0.2, the `ibm_db.dll` needs to be in subdirectory `ibm_db_dlls` in your
  bundle, which is the reason for specifying that destination on the
  `--add-binary` option.
- If you are building for Linux/Unix, instead of ^. use \ as the line continuation character as usual.
- If you intend to copy your built executable to a new hostname, and that new hostname does not already have a pre-installed Db2-client , and you do not wish to install a separate Db2-client on the target, then you can bundle clidriver with the pyinstaller output with the `--add-data` option shown above.
- If you bundle clidriver be aware that you may also need to bundle its configuration files (such as `db2dsdriver.cfg` and `db2cli.ini`) if they are in non-default locations, depending on whether your code uses externally configured DSNs or long connection-strings. If you do not bundle such configuration files (implicitly or explicitly) and you deploy your built environment to a different hostname than the build environment then you will need to reconfigure those files at the target hostname. The default location for these files is in the `clidriver\cfg` directory which will get included via `--add-data` as mentioned earlier.
- If you bundle clidriver, and if you are using encrypted connections to Db2 via TLS/SSL, be aware you may also need to bundle additional files such as certificates, keystore/stash files etc when you run the pyinstaller build.
- If you bundle clidriver, be aware that IBM refreshes this component a couple of times per year with bug fixes and security fixes and new functions, so you may need to refresh your executables periodically to prevent them from becoming security holes by being frozen in time with old versions.
- if you bundle clidriver and if you need to use `odbcad32` on the target hostname for configuring Db2 DSNs, then following deployment on the target hostname remember to run the `clidriver\bin\db2cli install -setup` command on the target hostname.

Comment: Thank you for all your help.  That finally did it.  I was able to get pyinstaller to correctly load and I can now launch the executable file.

Comment: Thank you so much for the help! I have looked for a solution to this for many years. I am using a spec file, and found that including the add-binary parameter you mentioned along with the hidden imports did the trick. However, I had to use the parameter, not the 'binaries' option in spec file. The clidriver got pulled in all by it's own. IBM_DB 3.0.2 Windows Python 2.7

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for your question and answer. I had met the same situation in Windows7 Python3.7 ibm-db 3.0.1
with your hint，I think the reason is that exe can't find *.dll in clidriver\bin and ibm_db.dll, 
and solve it with a similar method in two steps

**Frist:**
the same as you, add clidriver directory to system path

```
**\site-packages\clidriver\bin
```

**Second**
pack with argument --add-binary

```
 Pyinstaller --add-binary **\Lib\site-packages\ibm_db_dlls\ibm_db.dll;.\ibm_db_dlls myproject.py
```

Then it's OK！

**similar question:**
[PyQt5 Executable is crashing with Missing DLL](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55625610/pyqt5-executable-is-crashing-with-missing-dll/56076821#56076821)