# IBM_DB package for Python does not seem to have IBM_DB.dll

Tags: python-3.x, db2

Disclaimer:
I'm a newbie to Python.

I'm trying to access a DB2 database using Python for past couple of days and so far I'm unsuccessful in my attempts.

I have installed 'ibm_db' package by executing the command: *pip install ibm_db* and it seem to install successfully. So, I no longer get 'no module found for ibm_db' error when I try to import ibm_db. Also, I have set IBM_DB_HOME accordingly.

But, when I try to execute the below code, I get this error now: 
*ImportError: DLL load failed while importing ibm_db: The specified module could not be found.*

I have crawled the internet to see what I'm missing and found out that I dont have any IBM_DB_DLL folder nor the IBM_DB.dll.

How do I get these files?

**System and installation details:**

Windows 10 - 64 bit

Python version - Python 3.8.0 [MSC v.1916 64 bit (AMD64)] on win32 --I dont know what the *win32* means. I had installed this version(Windows x86-64 executable installer) from Python website.

I have also installed 'IBM DB2 Runtime Client 10.5fp8

IBM_DB_HOME variable is set to: C:\Python\Lib\site-packages

I was able to run other programs in Python. But, this is the first time Im trying to connect to DB2.

Any help or points are much appreciated.

Thanks in Advance,

Ganesh

```
def make_connexion(server, port, database, username, password, timeout):
return db2.connect('DATABASE={0};'.format(database) +
                  'HOSTNAME={0};'.format(server) +
                  'PORT={0};'.format(str(port)) +
                  'PROTOCOL=TCPIP;' +
                  'UID={0};'.format(username) +
                  'PWD={0};'.format(password) +
                  'ConnectTimeout={0};'.format(str(timeout))
                  , '', '')

--sample connexion object

connexion = make_connexion('server', 'port', 'database', 'username', 'password', 'timeout')
```

After uninstalling and reinstalling ibm_db package using easy_install ibm_db, I noticed the warning message that says *warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'ibm_db_dlls'*

Here's the full log when I tried to install ibm_db package

```
C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts>easy_install ibm_db
Searching for ibm_db
Reading https://pypi.org/simple/ibm_db/
Downloading https://files.pythonhosted.org/packages/98/cb/f77d9bd5f64246074af364cc30e20e3044c533890f3b67d30e89615c2fc5/ibm_db-3.0.1.tar.gz#sha256=a609e07295d16455d40df94ddd61b3d476606f5d44e3352103776e3ecbff185a
Best match: ibm-db 3.0.1
Processing ibm_db-3.0.1.tar.gz
Writing C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-vdcgwf_i\ibm_db-3.0.1\setup.cfg
Running ibm_db-3.0.1\setup.py -q bdist_egg --dist-dir C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-vdcgwf_i\ibm_db-3.0.1\egg-dist-tmp-3p_6emad
Detected 64-bit Python
Downloading https://public.dhe.ibm.com/ibmdl/export/pub/software/data/db2/drivers/odbc_cli/ntx64_odbc_cli.zip
warning: no files found matching '*' under directory 'ibm_db_dlls'
warning: no previously-included files found matching 'config.py'
ibm_db.c
ibm_db.c(268): warning C4267: 'initializing': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
ibm_db.c(279): warning C4267: 'initializing': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
ibm_db.c(467): warning C4047: '!=': 'SQLHANDLE' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
ibm_db.c(667): warning C4312: 'type cast': conversion from 'long' to 'SQLPOINTER' of greater size
ibm_db.c(699): warning C4312: 'type cast': conversion from 'long' to 'SQLPOINTER' of greater size
ibm_db.c(724): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
ibm_db.c(1257): warning C4312: 'type cast': conversion from 'long' to 'SQLPOINTER' of greater size
ibm_db.c(1305): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'SQLSMALLINT', possible loss of data
ibm_db.c(1307): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'SQLSMALLINT', possible loss of data
ibm_db.c(1309): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'SQLSMALLINT', possible loss of data
ibm_db.c(1305): warning C4996: 'PyUnicode_GetSize': deprecated in 3.3
c:\users\me\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include\unicodeobject.h(177): note: see declaration of 'PyUnicode_GetSize'
ibm_db.c(1307): warning C4996: 'PyUnicode_GetSize': deprecated in 3.3
c:\users\me\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include\unicodeobject.h(177): note: see declaration of 'PyUnicode_GetSize'
ibm_db.c(1309): warning C4996: 'PyUnicode_GetSize': deprecated in 3.3
c:\users\me\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include\unicodeobject.h(177): note: see declaration of 'PyUnicode_GetSize'
ibm_db.c(1452): warning C4244: 'initializing': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
ibm_db.c(1920): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'INT_PTR' to 'int', possible loss of data
ibm_db.c(2019): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'INT_PTR' to 'int', possible loss of data
ibm_db.c(2305): warning C4312: 'type cast': conversion from 'unsigned long' to 'SQLPOINTER' of greater size
ibm_db.c(2679): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
ibm_db.c(5155): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
ibm_db.c(5155): warning C4996: 'PyUnicode_GetSize': deprecated in 3.3
c:\users\me\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include\unicodeobject.h(177): note: see declaration of 'PyUnicode_GetSize'
ibm_db.c(5352): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'SQLINTEGER', possible loss of data
ibm_db.c(5387): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'SQLINTEGER', possible loss of data
ibm_db.c(5478): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'SQLINTEGER', possible loss of data
ibm_db.c(5489): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'SQLINTEGER', possible loss of data
ibm_db.c(5504): warning C4018: '<=': signed/unsigned mismatch
ibm_db.c(5520): warning C4018: '<=': signed/unsigned mismatch
ibm_db.c(5616): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'SQLINTEGER', possible loss of data
ibm_db.c(5627): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'SQLINTEGER', possible loss of data
ibm_db.c(5641): warning C4018: '<=': signed/unsigned mismatch
ibm_db.c(5766): warning C4267: '=': conversion from 'size_t' to 'SQLINTEGER', possible loss of data
ibm_db.c(5489): warning C4996: 'PyUnicode_GetSize': deprecated in 3.3
c:\users\me\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\include\unicodeobject.h(177): note: see declaration of 'PyUnicode_GetSize'
ibm_db.c(5995): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
ibm_db.c(5966): warning C4101: 'curr_ptr': unreferenced local variable
ibm_db.c(5966): warning C4101: 'prev_ptr': unreferenced local variable
ibm_db.c(7734): warning C4047: '!=': 'SQLHANDLE' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
ibm_db.c(7747): warning C4047: '=': 'SQLHANDLE' differs in levels of indirection from 'int'
ibm_db.c(8313): warning C4267: 'function': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
ibm_db.c(8318): warning C4267: 'function': conversion from 'size_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
ibm_db.c(10318): warning C4244: 'function': conversion from 'SQLINTEGER' to 'SQLSMALLINT', possible loss of data
ibm_db.c(10437): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
ibm_db.c(10454): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
ibm_db.c(10738): warning C4244: '=': conversion from 'Py_ssize_t' to 'int', possible loss of data
ibm_db.c(10805): warning C4047: '==': 'SQLINTEGER' differs in levels of indirection from 'void *'
   Creating library build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\ibm_db.cp38-win_amd64.lib and object build\temp.win-amd64-3.8\Release\ibm_db.cp38-win_amd64.exp
Generating code
c:\users\me\appdata\local\temp\easy_install-vdcgwf_i\ibm_db-3.0.1\ibm_db.c(7195) : warning C4715: 'ibm_db_field_nullable': not all control paths return a value
Finished generating code
zip_safe flag not set; analyzing archive contents...
__pycache__.ibm_db.cpython-38: module references __file__
__pycache__.testfunctions.cpython-38: module MAY be using inspect.stack
tests.__pycache__.test_000_PrepareDb.cpython-38: module references __file__
tests.__pycache__.test_144_BindParamInsertStmtPARAM_FILE.cpython-38: module references __file__

****************************************
You are downloading a package which includes the Python module for IBM DB2/Informix.  The module is licensed under the Apache License 2.0. The package also includes IBM ODBC and CLI Driver from IBM, which is automatically downloaded as the python module is installed on your system/device. The license agreement to the IBM ODBC and CLI Driver is available in c:\users\me\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\Lib\site-packages\clidriver or c:\users\me\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\Lib\site-packages\ibm_db-3.0.1-py3.8.egg\clidriver.   Check for additional dependencies, which may come with their own license agreement(s). Your use of the components of the package and dependencies constitutes your acceptance of their respective license agreements. If you do not accept the terms of any license agreement(s), then delete the relevant component(s) from your device.
****************************************
creating c:\users\me\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\ibm_db-3.0.1-py3.8-win-amd64.egg
Extracting ibm_db-3.0.1-py3.8-win-amd64.egg to c:\users\me\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages
Adding ibm-db 3.0.1 to easy-install.pth file

Installed c:\users\me\appdata\local\programs\python\python38\lib\site-packages\ibm_db-3.0.1-py3.8-win-amd64.egg
Processing dependencies for ibm_db
Finished processing dependencies for ibm_db

C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python38\Scripts>
```

Comment: Does this answer your question? [ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found -- IBM DB2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55839589/importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found-ibm-db2)

Comment: Thanks Charles. Does it mean I need to install PyInstaller and SQLalchemy to execute those steps?

Comment: I had tried to follow the instructions on this page: ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found -- IBM DB2. But, where do I find IBM_DB.dll? I dont seem to find this .dll anywhere in my computer. Do I need to install any other package which contains the .dll?

Comment: What platform / operating system are you on? What version of Python? Do other Python programs work?

Comment: Thank you @data_henrik & mao. I have updated my question. I will try uninstalling ibm_db package and reinstall it.

Comment: Additionally, the ibm_db module for python works fine with Python 3.7.x (but I do not know if it works with Python 3.8).  Your updates to the quesiton show that the easy_install (alternative to pip) is trying to install the clidriver ( = the IBM Data Server driver for ODBC and CLI) because IBM_DB_HOME is either unset or has wrong value, per my previous remark.

Comment: thanks @mao. I think I have gone backwards now. I have verified that DB2 runtime client is a 64 bit one and I have 64 bit Python version installed in my machine. I've set IBM_DB_HOME to ```C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB``` where IBM DB2 runtime client is installed.

Comment: But, when I try to install ibm_db using ```easy_install ibm_db``` Im getting this error message ```Cannot find C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB\lib directory. Check if you have set the IBM_DB_HOME environment variable's value correctly
 No eggs found in C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-2ckkf5vp\ibm_db-3.0.1\egg-dist-tmp-epa8qskj (setup script problem?)```. Even, when I try with ```pip install ibm_db``` Im getting a similar error.

Comment: Unfortunately, that did not fix my issue. I see two issues: 1. Even though my IBM_DB_HOME is set to "C:Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB", easy install seems to look for "C:\Program Files\IBM\SQLLIB"**\lib** directory and I dont see a \lib directory in DB2 Runtime client installation. 2. Both easy_install and pip install complaining about ```No eggs found in C:\Users\me\AppData\Local\Temp\easy_install-df3gcxkg\ibm_db-3.0.1\egg-dist-tmp-6cxnd2md (setup script problem?)```. How do I get this file? P.S. Im truly sorry for the extensiveness of this issue.

Comment: See https://github.com/ibmdb/python-ibmdb/issues/456

Answer (score 1):

I personally was unable to install IBM DB v3.0.1 on my Python 3.8 installation. Got numerous errors and whatnot. However, I encountered no issues on 3.7.4 install.

Answer (score 0):

Here is one of Python + Db2 starting technote:

**Installing Python on un-networked / offline machines where Db2 is installed**
http://www.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=ibm10730749

Here is snippet :

Db2 product can be installed without internet connection but
Python modules and adapters may need to connect the internet.

If the un-networked machine can connect an internet proxy server, may work
around by using HTTP_PROXY environment variable for easy_install and
--proxy option for pip.

But if no proxy/internet connection machine, here is an example
how to install it on a Windows machine by copying eggs.

It is recommended to install the same version of Python on two boxes below.
  Box [A] : internet connectable machine
  Box [B] : un-networked machine, such as development box where
            DB2 V11.1 M3 FP3 installed

In this example, use below Knowledge Center page and will get 8 modules/products:
**Python downloads and related resources**
https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSEPGG_11.1.0/com.ibm.sw…

- Python
- SQLAlchemy
- Django
- ibm_db and ibm_db_dbi extensions (including source code)
- ibm_db_sa adapter for SQLAlchemy 0.4
- ibm_db_django adaptor for Django 1.0.x and 1.1
- setuptools program
- IBM Data Server Driver Package (DS Driver)

It describes about how to un-networked machine installation.  But the
steps should be worked on one box machine case as well.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks @hidehy. Would you mind providing the correct URL? I tried to find the right one, but so far couldn't.

Comment: Hi @Ganesh, Here is the one.  Hope it works.
https://www.ibm.com/support/pages/installing-python-un-networked-offline-machines-where-db2-installed

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I was able to install *ibm_db* package successfully containing *'ibm_db_dll's*. After I deleted the *IBM_DB_HOME* environment variable, and running this command *'easy_install ibm_db'*, the ibm_db package installed successfully.

Answer (score 0):

Use an older version of Python:
I have tried to install ibm-db on many versions. I found out that ibm-db could not be installed for Python version 3.8.1 and 3.8.2 while it could be installed for version 3.7.7. But also take note to not use version 3.6 or older as there are issues with the executions in Python that are present in older versions. In total, download Python above version 3.6 and below 3.8.