# ImportError: DLL load failed - Only when using IBM DB module

Tags: python, python-3.x, dll, db2, pyinstaller

Am observing "DLL LOAD FAILED error message while running my python file as a exe file in a server where Python or internet connect is not available. My other exe files are not having any issues, this file containing IBM DB module is the only one having issues.

I tried the solution given here: [ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found -- IBM DB2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/55839589/importerror-dll-load-failed-the-specified-module-could-not-be-found-ibm-db2) - Still am facing the trouble.

When I run this same exe file in my local machine (laptop) - its Working, but in Server - its not working.

Below is the command I used to convert exe file:

```
pyinstaller -y --additional-hooks-dir=. --hidden-import ibm_db_sa.ibm_db --hidden-import ibm_db_dbi --hidden-import ibm_db --add-binary C:\Python\Python37\Lib\site-packages\ibm_db_dlls\ibm_db.dll;.\ibm_db_dlls --onefile mypythonfile.py
```

Below is the error message when I run the exe file:

```
E:\SuspenseReport>mypythonfile.exe
c:\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importers.py:62
3: MatplotlibDeprecationWarning:
The MATPLOTLIBDATA environment variable was deprecated in Matplotlib 3.1 and wil
l be removed in 3.3.
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "mypythonfile.py", line 14, in <module>
    import ibm_db
  File "c:\python\python37\lib\site-packages\PyInstaller\loader\pyimod03_importe
rs.py", line 623, in exec_module
  File "site-packages\ibm_db.py", line 10, in <module>
  File "site-packages\ibm_db.py", line 9, in __bootstrap__
  File "imp.py", line 342, in load_dynamic
ImportError: DLL load failed: The specified module could not be found.
[16360] Failed to execute script mypythonfile
```

Versions:

```
Python Version: 3.7.6
Pyinstaller Version: 3.6
ibm-db Version: 3.0.1
os : Windows
```

Please advise what can be done to fix this issue.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I updated the other answer that you reference.

If your python code does not explicitly use SQLAlchemy you don't need to include it on the pyinstaller build command line. If you are using SQLAlchemy then you may need the additional hooks mentioned in the other answer.

As you are deploying your EXE on a different hostname (server) than your build environment (workstation), the target server might not already have a Db2-client installed.

python ibm_db uses CLI (call level interface) to access Db2 databases. A Db2-client provides such a CLI interface. If you do not have any Db2-client available to ibm_db, then ibm_db module will fail to load and you will see your symptom. When you install ibm_db, by default it will add a small Db2-client (zero install) called clidriver on your workstation, but that will not get included by pyinstaller in your bundle.

If the server has no Db2-client installed already, and you do NOT wish to separately install and configure a Db2-client, then you can rebuild your pyinstaller bundle to include the `clidriver` that the python ibm_db module delivers by default.  To rebuild, you need to include additional command-line options to pyinstaller.

To include the clidriver, first find its location via the command `pip show ibm_db` and then find the `Location:` value , and to this path append the `\clidriver` value. This is the fully qualified path to your clidriver for example `c:\path\to\clidriver`

Next, re-run your previous pyinstaller command with the additional option

`--add-data="c:\path\to\clidriver;.\clidriver`"

If your python code depends on externally configured DSNs (instead of long connection strings inside the code) and if you made a suitable `db2dsdriver.cfg` file containing those DSNs and any parameters each database or DSN needs, then you will also need to include that `db2dsdriver.cfg` file in your bundle.  If your code does not rely on externally configured DSNs then this step may not be needed. You can also script `db2cli` command lines to run on the server to configure the `db2dsdriver.cfg` instead of bundling it, if that is your preference.

If you need to use the `odbcad32.exe` executable on the target server hostname to configure Db2 DSNs, you will also need to run the clidriver setup command-line on the target server after you deliver your pyinstaller built EXE file by running its `db2cli install -setup` executable from the clidriver\bin directory as administrator. If you do NOT need to use GUIs like `odbcad32.exe` on the target hostname then this step can be omitted.

If you are using encrypted connections to Db2 (i.e. SSL/TLS), or certificate based authentication, then  your bundle may also need to include relevant certificates, and/or keystores/stashes. So you may need additional options to your pyinstaller build.

On the target server, it may be useful to add the fully qualified clidriver\bin directory to the PATH environment variable.  Ensure that the directories that contain any configuration files or data files are readable to any user or group that needs to access them.

In addition be aware that IBM updates its clidriver software a couple of times each year, with security fixes and bug fixes along with new features. After testing, your pyinstaller built EXE should be refreshed and redistributed to include refreshed clidriver.

Comment: Thanks a lot for the detailed explanation. -add-data for the CLI driver worked for my problem. Thanks again for your inputs.